# Is it possible to create a xsl variable from javascript?

Tags: javascript, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<xsl:variable name="delivery">
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById('id').value;</script>
</xsl:variable>
```

Is it possible to create a xsl variable from javascript like the example above?

Comment: You can store virtually anything in a variable. But the interesting question is: What are you really trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Take a look here: http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/70455-how-pass-javascript-variable-xsl.html

Comment: Why would you? Just pass the value into the transform as a parameter. It's (certainly) not changing its value dynamically while the transform is taking place, which means you can pass in the value at the time of transformation as xsl:param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XSLT transformation happens first, then in a second, separate step a browser might render the transformation result containing some script code and execute the script as well. So with your sample

```
<xsl:variable name="delivery">
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById('id').value;</script>
</xsl:variable>
```

during XSLT transformation the value of the `delivery` variable is a result tree fragment containing a `script` element node containing a text node (which happens to be client-side Javascript code), but no script execution happens during the XSLT transformation.